# why QSerialPort read() method doesn't work as expected?

Tags: qt, serial-port

I'm going to write 5 bytes of data to a COM port and expect to receive 11 with the last byte of 0xFF to receive. I store the receiving bytes in `pantilt_value` variable.

This is a code which works:
(I receive the 11 bytes as expected with the last byte of 0xFF)

```
_port->write(data_pantilt, 5);
QByteArray pantilt_value = _port->readAll();
while (_port->waitForReadyRead(100))
    pantilt_value.append(_port->readAll());
```

This is a code which doesn't work:
(I receive just a first 2 bytes)

```
_port->write(data_pantilt, 5);
char d;
QByteArray pantilt_value;
while (_port->waitForReadyRead(100)){
   _port->read(&d,1);
   pantilt_value.append(d);
   if (d == 0xff)
       break;
}
```

Can you explain why the second code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`waitForReadyRead()` returns `true` only when there is **new** data available. In your second case, the while loop has time to execute twice before all data is received. Use [`QSerialPort::bytesAvailable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#bytesAvailable) to see how much data there is to be read.

Comment: Thank you @thuga that was the case :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, The first time you call `waitForReadyRead()` to check if there is a data on serial port to read, it returns `true`, but you should read the whole data on the serial port after you call that method because if you fail to read the whole data after calling `waitForReadyRead()`, next time you call that method, it returns `false`, although there is still some data left to read from the port.

So my second code should be changed to something like this:

```
_port->write(data_pantilt, 5);
char d;
QByteArray pantilt_value;
while(_port->waitForReadyRead(100)){
    while (_port->bytesAvailable() > 0){
       _port->read(&d,1);
       pantilt_value.append(d);
       if (d == 0xff)
           break;
    }
}
```